# How can I change Pentaho Mondrian 4 cache lifetime?

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

How can I change Pentaho Mondrian 4 cache lifetime?

I want to reduce it to 5 min but in the property file no such property is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean mondrian-catalog-cache,

Follow the following steps.

 1) Stop BA server 

 2) Navigate to \biserver-ee\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\classes 

 3) Take back up of file "ehcache.xml" 

 4) Open File "ehcache.xml" 

 5) Scroll down to content

```
<cache name="mondrian-catalog-cache"
maxElementsInMemory="30"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true"
timeToIdleSeconds="0"
timeToLiveSeconds="0"
diskPersistent="false"
diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
/>
```

6) Change the values of

> timeToIdleSeconds, timeToLiveSeconds, diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds

7) Save and Restart BA server  

 Other caches also can be changed as such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to set up to flushing period of the Mondrian cache in `mondrian.properties` file.

Try to use [Community Distributed Cache](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cdc/) if you use Pentaho BI server. You can download it in the marketplace. It might help to solve your problems with caching.